# (How) can a smart contract mint a token that it does not own?

Tags: solidity

I have the supply key of the token but it has no admin key so I cannot change its ownership and make it owned by the smart contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Token is an ERC-20 token, its mint function would be "internal" and can be called by the token contract itself, our any child contract that inherited from the token contract. See the following code:

```
function _mint(address account, uint256 value) internal {
    if (account == address(0)) {
        revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
    }
    _update(address(0), account, value);
}
```

So if you write a minter smart contract and inherit that from token contract, you must be able to call mint function of token.

see below link to see code samples:

[HederaTokenService.sol](https://github.com/ed-marquez/hedera-general-examples/blob/main/src/017_contract_treasury_sol/HederaTokenService.sol)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, a smart contract cannot mint tokens it does not own, unless it has explicit permissions. Token minting is typically restricted to the contract owner or authorized addresses. If a token contract lacks an admin key, standard minting functions won't be available. However, custom functionalities or permissions may allow external contracts to mint under specific conditions.